# Why am I getting a warning related to 'type name collision' using graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter?

Tags: java, graphql, spring-boot-starter, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

Could someone please help me here, I'm getting a warning something related to 'type name collision' as follows. I'm using graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter.

```
2020-06-06 19:04:15.972  WARN 22428 --- [           main] i.l.graphql.generator.OperationMapper    : Potential type name collision detected: 'String' bound to multiple types: java.lang.String (loaded by the bootstrap class loader) and @javax.validation.Valid() java.lang.String (loaded by the bootstrap class loader). Assign unique names using the appropriate annotations or override the TypeInfoGenerator. For details and solutions see https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/wiki/Errors#non-unique-type-name. If this warning is a false positive, please report it: https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues.
```

I referred to the page https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/wiki/Errors#non-unique-type-name but couldn't find/understand how to fix it. I'm new to graphql, anyone's help would be much appreciated.

Comment: GraphQL has no concept of namespacing and enforces unique names on types.
Probably you need  @GraphQLType(name = "your custom conflict class name")
See: https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues/232

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://gitter.im/leangen/graphql-spqr?at=5c6457dd28c89123cbc265aa) your warning is benign.

> If two different types end up with the same name, it will log a warning.
> A type is a fully qualified annotated, generic type. So even a single annotation differing is enough to trigger it.
> In your case, `String` and `@Valid String` are different types.
> The reasoning is that annotations can influence the mapping.